# Newly seasoned carbon steel pan sticks when cooking

Tags: pan, seasoning

After doing reasearch I decided to try a less expensive pan when buying a 12".  Bought a Paderno and did a mix of seasoning with organic flax seed oil.  I did about 5 coats on the stove top per instructions (heating, adding small amount of oil and rubbing it down with paper towel, heat/ cool / repeat.  For good measure I also tried rubbing the entire pan with oil and cooked in 400 degree oven for 2 hours and let it cool in oven for 2 hours.  The 2 times I've cooked anything in it (eggs with onions) everything sticks.  Never had this problem with my small de Buyer crepe pan.  One chef recommended 11 coats, I think I've got 7.  Wondering now if I put on too many coats of oil or if this made in China pan is just an inferior metal.

Comment: Welcome to the site @LeslieHarris. Seasoning does not make a pan equivalent to a non-stick coating. Are you using oil when cooking? How long are you pre-heating your pan?

Comment: Though flax seed oil polymerises very easily, making it a perfect 'base layer' for pan seasoning, it also tends to have a slightly sticky finish. I always do a few layers of flax seed, then finish off with a layer or two vegetable (rapeseed) oil. This gives it a much more smooth, slippery surface which rarely sticks.

Comment: Thanks for that, @canardgras. I'll try that on my cast iron. I've been using flaxseed and have been pretty happy but not 100% happy with the coating.

Comment: Thank you.  I've now been coating the pan with EVOO before and after every use.  I'll try finding rapeseed oil. After cooking bacon in it a few times, it seems to be working much better.  Thanks for all comments.

Answer (score -1):

High temps and flaxseed oil (essentially linseed oil) don't mix so I'd be suspicious of using flaxseed oil for seasoning. Try using a different oil and see what happens. The baked coating may then be less sticky/grabby.